# nltk pos_tag usage

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to use speech tagging in NLTK and have used this command:

```
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")

>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
nltk.pos_tag(text)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load
resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 686, in _open
return find(path).open()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 467, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not
found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
```

However, I get an error message which shows:

```
engish.pickle not found.
```

I have download the whole corpora and the english.pickle file is there in the maxtent_treebank_pos_tagger

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try and be as descriptive as possible in your questions to get the best answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Python installation is not able to reach maxent or treemap.

First, check if the tagger is indeed there:
Start Python from the command line.

`>>> import nltk`

Then you can check using

`>>> dir (nltk)`

Look through the list to see if `maxent` and `treebank` are both there.

Easier would be to type

```
>>> "maxent" in dir(nltk)
>>> True
>>> "treebank" in dir(nltk)
>>> True
```

Use `nltk.download()` --> Models tab and check to see if the treemap tagger shows as installed.
You should also try downloading the tagger again.

[image: NLTK Downloader, Models Tab]

Comment: thnks @ram i got the sollution to my problem. i created a folder taggers and copied the maxtent_treebank_pos in that and it finally works..:)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the downloader gui, you can just use the following commands in a python or ipython shell:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
```

Comment: This works perfect for me, but why is that i need to run it all the time if i close the shell

Answer (score 0):

Over 50 corpora and lexical resources such as WordNet: http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ for free.
Use http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/ as server index instead of googlecode
Google code 401: Authorization Required