# NLTK error loading module

Tags: python, nltk

Im trying to run this code:

```
import nltk


text = "Mrs. Hudson made a cup of tea. She is a wonderful woman."
sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)#breaks statement into       
print sentences
#print tokens
tokens = [nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]#tokenizes sentences passes as list of lists

PosTokens = [nltk.pos_tag(e) for e in tokens]
```

When I run it I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'averaged_perceptron_tagger' is not defined
```

So I run the downloader to get the tagger and per this question I need 'maxtent_treebank_pos_tagger'
[nltk pos_tag usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089887/nltk-pos-tag-usage)

and I get the following:

```
nltk.download('maxtent_treebank_pos-tagger')

NameError: name 'averaged_perceptron_tagger' is not defined
>>> nltk.download('maxtent_treebank_pos-tagger')
[nltk_data] Error loading maxtent_treebank_pos-tagger: Package
[nltk_data]     'maxtent_treebank_pos-tagger' not found in index
False
```

So Im stumped thanks for the help all!!!

Comment: Your problem is a typo: It's "maxent" (maximum entropy), not "maxtent".

Comment: [nltk_data] Error loading maxent: Package 'maxent' not found in index
False

Comment: @alvas this is a problem about a typo, not a duplicate about how to use the tagger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I was importing a typo

its nltk.download(maxent_treebank_pos_tagger)